# AngularJS: TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to use a service inside my angular controller, however I am getting the error in the `TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined`.

This is how my `app.js` script look like:

```
angular
    .module('ToDoApp', ['ngAnimate', 'todoService'])
    .controller('ToDoController', ['$scope', function($scope, $http, Todo) {

        Todo.get()
            .success(function(data) {
                $scope.tasks = data;
            });
        // ...
     }]);
```

It doesn't know about the `get` propery. This is how `Todo` looks like:

```
angular.module('todoService', [])
    .factory('Todo', function($http) {
        return {
            get: function() {
                return $http.get('/todos');
            },
            // ...
        }
    });
```

And I'm loading the scripts in this order:

```
<script src="{{ asset('/scripts/services/todoService.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('/scripts/app.js') }}"></script>
```

The error sounds to me like the controller isn't getting the service object correctly, like this dependency is missing. But I already loaded the dependency with the `module`.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deleted my previous comment, figured out what you had wrong. You're using the array notation to fix minification, but you're only listing `$scope`, you need to list the others as well, meaning you need to add the `$http` and the `ToDo`:

```
angular
    .module('ToDoApp', ['ngAnimate', 'todoService'])
    .controller('ToDoController', ['$scope', '$http', 'ToDo', function($scope, $http, Todo) {

        Todo.get()
            .success(function(data) {
                $scope.tasks = data;
            });
        // ...
     }]);
```